# Какой язык программирования стоит учить для ios и одновременно android. Мобильные игры

Tags: android, ios

Ребят, посоветуйте *язык **программирования***, который нормально работает на ***iOS*** *&* ***AndroidOS***. Лично я использую **Windows**. Посоветуйте любой ***язык программирования***, пж

Comment: Одинаковых нативных языков для этих платформ нет, как написали в ответе, в iOS это Swift, в Android - Java/Kotlin, но есть кроссплатформенные решения: Xamarin - C#, Flutter - Dart, React Native - JS. видимо вам первый вариант подходит, так как Xamarin это тема Microsoft, то есть тут и Visual Studio и C#/ Что касается именно игр, то это Unity и все тот же C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS - это Swift (Apple co)
AndroidOS - это Java (Oracle co) / Kotlin (Google его продвигает)

Общего языка у них нету :)

Comment: зачем вы форматируете обычный текст, как код? и Есть [кросплатформенные решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124987/Какой-язык-программирования-стоит-учить-для-ios-и-одновременно-android-Мобильны#comment1944355_1124987)

Comment: А Minecraft на iPhone не на Java??

Comment: @Mr_CatYT нет, на C++

Comment: @DmitrySerov мой мир перевернулся на изнанку

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о кроссплатформенных приложениях, то

```
Kotlin для KotlinNative
Dart для Flutter
JavaScript для ReactNative
```